# actionscript 2 print as pdf at runtime gets cut off

Tags: pdf, printing, actionscript, export, actionscript-2

when I try to print a FLASH SWF (ActionScript 2.0) at runtime the print area is always cut off at the bottom right corner. How do I print to pdf at runtime and print everything that exist on the stage ?

I used the PrintJob process but it does not seem to work. I have setup the print area 1900 x 1400 but it remains trimmed.

```
printbutton.onRelease = function()
  {
    var pj = new PrintJob();
    var success = pj.start();
    if (success)
        {//Centered Variables
        pj.addPage(0,{xMin:0, xMax:1900, yMin:0, yMax:1400});
        pj.send();
        }
        delete pj;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

check page orientation. you can use the below example:

```
printbutton.onRelease = function(){
 // create PrintJob object
 var pj:PrintJob = new PrintJob();

 // display print dialog box
 if (pj.start()) {
    // boolean to track whether addPage succeeded, change this to a counter
    // if more than one call to addPage is possible
    var pageAdded:Boolean = false;

    // check the user's printer orientation setting
    // and add appropriate print area to print job
    if (pj.orientation == "portrait") {
    pageAdded = pj.addPage(0,{xMin:0, xMax:1400, yMin:0, yMax:1900});
    }
    else {
    // pj.orientation is "landscape"
    pageAdded = pj.addPage(0,{xMin:0, xMax:1900, yMin:0, yMax:1400});
    }

    // send pages from the spooler to the printer
    if (pageAdded) {
    pj.send(); 
    }
 }
 // clean up
 delete pj;
};
```